# remove bulletstyle on WPF richtextbox selection

Tags: wpf, vb.net, richtextbox

I've managed to applying bulleted list formatting possible, but how to remove it again?
How to detect if the selection is/contains a `List`?
Did I overcomplicate things? Is there a straightword way to convert a selection to a bulleted list and back?

```
 Private Sub bullet(o As Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip, e As Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs)
    Dim lst As New Windows.Documents.List()
    lst.MarkerStyle = bullets(e.ClickedItem.Text)
    If rtf.Selection.IsEmpty Then
        lst.ListItems.Add(New Windows.Documents.ListItem())
    Else
        Dim li As Windows.Documents.ListItem
        Dim lines() As String = rtf.Selection.Text.Split(vbCrLf)
        For Each s As String In lines
            li = New Windows.Documents.ListItem()
            li.Blocks.Add(New Windows.Documents.Paragraph(New Windows.Documents.Run(s.Trim())))
            lst.ListItems.Add(li)
        Next
        rtf.Selection.Text = ""
    End If
    Dim curCaret = rtf.CaretPosition
    Dim curBlock = rtf.Document.Blocks.Where(Function(x) x.ContentStart.CompareTo(curCaret) = -1 AndAlso x.ContentEnd.CompareTo(curCaret) = 1).FirstOrDefault()
    rtf.Document.Blocks.InsertAfter(curBlock, lst)
    Dim vMove As Windows.Documents.TextPointer = Nothing

    vMove = curCaret.GetNextInsertionPosition(Windows.Documents.LogicalDirection.Forward)
    If vMove IsNot Nothing Then rtf.CaretPosition = vMove

    rtf.Focus()
End Sub
```

I've since come to drop this code from my project because it's unreliable in certain situations. Would a solution based on dynamic XAML  insertion be more reliable? Many aspects of WPF  seem to very poorly conceived....

Answer (score 0):

If you could use the windows forms version of richtextbox, you could use the `SelectionBullet` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742875.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try `EditingCommands.ToggleBullets.Execute(null, richTextBox)` to toggle bullet style in selected paragraphs.